# Display results from filter formula in one row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using a filter formula to output multiple results based on a condition. Each result contains 4 columns of data, each result is in a new row. However, I would like all results to be output one after the other (i.e. in one row). The data of each result takes up 4 columns and in the fifth column, the new result starts with 4 columns.

This is how it looks now:
[image: Current status]

This is how it should look:
[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1):

To get this dynamically, follow these steps.

1 - in the sheet where you want the results on cell A2 past this formula.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(QUERY(Data!A2:D," Select * where A is not null ")))
```

- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) because [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) formula outputs a column.
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to remove blank rows.
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) to convert all values from one or more ranges into a single column.

2 - to make the header dynamic you need to paste this formula in resault sheet in cell A1.

```
=SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(";",Data!A1:D1)&";",COUNTA(Data!A2:A)),";")
```

- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) the header with `;` so you can split it with the [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) formula after repeating the header rang n time with the [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en) formula, to handel how many times the header repeated just use [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) to count how many rows are there.

Input example:
[image]

Output example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to use `Flatten()` to make it a one dimensional array since the spreadsheet data is in a nested array no matter how many rows/columns you have.

[image]

Then from here you can just transpose the data so instead of the data going down the rows it will be transposed to go horizontally to the columns.

**Try:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(A2:D))
```

To combine it with your formula just replace the Range **"A2:D"** with your current formula.

**Result:**
[image]

**References:**

- [Transpose](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [Flatten](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)